# Programa para hacer el abecedario en C

Tags: c

Hace poco estaba haciendo un pequeño programa en C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {


    char caracter = 'a';

    while(caracter<='z') {
        printf("%c \n",caracter);



        if(caracter == 'n') {
            printf("ñ \n");
        }

        caracter++;
    }

}
```

Pero la verdad no entiendo muy bien, o sea cómo funciona internamente el aumento en los Caracteres, o sea en los números es fácil:

```
int numero = 1;
numero++ //2,3,4...

//Pero los Caracteres?

char caracter = 'a'
caracter++; //Como funciona esto?
```

Y por último en mi programa implementé un if que añadía la ñ, pero ¿hay una forma de hacer esto sin el if o una manera más optimizada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando defines a una variable de tipo **`char`**, almacena el valor en caracter [**`ASCII`**](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/), veamos un ejemplo:

```
char caracter = 'a'; // es equivalente a 61h o 61 hexadecimal
char caracter = 'b'; // es equivalente a 62h o 62 hexadecimal
...
```

Y en donde **`caracter++;`** hace que el valor hexadecimal de **`caracter`** aumente, dando como resultado la letra del abecedario (el caracter **ASCII**):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char caracter = 'a'; // la letra "a" es igual a 61 hexadecimal o 61h

    // hacemos un while, en donde el while se romperá cuando "caracter" sea "z"
    while (caracter <= 'z')
    {
        printf("%c \n", caracter); // imprimimos a "caracter" con un salto de línea

        if (caracter == 'n')
        {
            printf("ñ \n");
        }

        caracter++; // 61h = a, 62h = b, 63h = c... irá incrementando.
    }
}
```

Comment: Es **hexadecimal**.

Comment: Ok ya lo corregí, gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Las computadoras solo entienden 1s y 0s.

No existe tal cosa como los caracteres, sino una interpretación para cada conjunto de bits. A esto se le llama codificación y [existen muchas para caracteres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Por ejemplo [ASCII](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) creada para Windows y [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), nuevo estándar internacional [ISO/IEC 10646](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_10646), ambas basadas en la anterior. <sup>[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages)</sup>

C no impone ningún estándar en particular. Lo que sí menciona es que contarás con al menos las 52 letras mayúsculas y minúsculas del alfabeto latino, los dígitos del 0 al 9, los símbolos `! " # % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~`, el espacio y caracteres de control. <sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996106)</sup>

---

Convenientemente en ASCII (y otras codificaciones basadas en él) todas las letras del alfabeto inglés están codificadas con números consecutivos.

Entonces al aumentar el caracter **a** (97 en decimal), estás sumándole 1 a 97. Entonces obtienes 98 que corresponde a la **b** y así sucesivamente.

Te dejo este código para que se te haga más evidente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    for (int i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
        printf("%c (%d)\n", i, i);
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw46LKzOvRCE3MTNPQ7OaSwEI0vKLFDRAgpkKtgrqjurWQIYNkBUFYmlra4IVgUBBEVBVmoaSarKChmqKZkyeko5CJhBpWnPV/v8PAA).

---

La `ñ` está aparte en el código ASCII. Así que, por simplicidad y compatibilidad con cualquier codificación, puedes escribir un arreglo con todas las letras y recorrerlo.

```
char abecedario[] = "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";

for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    printf("%c\n", abecedario[i]);
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##TY1LDoIwFEXnXcVLjQkENcaJA9CNKIPy2sJTaLGA37go1@DCamHkmZzJ/eCyRPR@RgbrQSrIul6SXVV7xsj00AgyUfxiEMBKOBCFQiWFI3vIYQdcFCiVLis6nevGfD@2vbiuH663@@PJUzYVtXUQjWsUGus0KIPNNjhJ4ikw0rqQ0BGf49Hwxf8P5XHK3t7/AA).

[Respuesta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41310110).

Answer (score 2):

Hasta donde entiendo, es porque se incrementa el valor en el entero decimal que representa en la tabla ASCII.

La "ñ", hasta donde entiendo, no tiene un valor en la tabla ASCII como un caracter, sino que es tratado como una cadena y por eso su procesamiento deberá ser a parte, justo como tú lo estás haciendo. No sé la razón de esto último.

Cuando incrementas o comparas con los operadores "++" o "<", etc, lo que haces es comparar no el valor como letra, sino como su entero en la tabla ASCII.

Por ejemplo, reformateando tu código:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    for(char caracter = 'a'; caracter <= 'z'; caracter++) {
        printf("ASCII value: %i, char value: %c \n", caracter, caracter);
        if(caracter == 'n') {
            char *ene = "ñ";
            printf("Whatever value: %i, char value: %s \n", ene, ene);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Nos da esto:

```
ASCII value: 97, char value: a
ASCII value: 98, char value: b
ASCII value: 99, char value: c
ASCII value: 100, char value: d
ASCII value: 101, char value: e
ASCII value: 102, char value: f
ASCII value: 103, char value: g
ASCII value: 104, char value: h
ASCII value: 105, char value: i
ASCII value: 106, char value: j
ASCII value: 107, char value: k
ASCII value: 108, char value: l
ASCII value: 109, char value: m
ASCII value: 110, char value: n
Whatever value: -1014915030, char value: ñ
ASCII value: 111, char value: o
ASCII value: 112, char value: p
ASCII value: 113, char value: q
ASCII value: 114, char value: r
ASCII value: 115, char value: s
ASCII value: 116, char value: t
ASCII value: 117, char value: u
ASCII value: 118, char value: v
ASCII value: 119, char value: w
ASCII value: 120, char value: x
ASCII value: 121, char value: y
ASCII value: 122, char value: z
```

Aquí puedes ver como nuestro nuevo código corresonde con los valores de la tabla ASCII: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters